# Dynamic form action - how to catch that with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, javascript, session

There is a page at http://www.cipo.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/tmSrch.do?lang=eng

When you do a search, it generates a custom URL, for example, http://www.cipo.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/bldSrch.do;jsessionid=00017eoN13xc3cyM5WYxwkO2v3I:-118SGKV?lang=eng&textField1=trademark&selectField1=tmlookup_ext&submitButton=Search&andOr1=and&textField2=consulting&selectField2=services&andOr2=and&textField3=&selectField3=tmlookup_ext&andOr3=and&textField4=&selectField4=tmlookup_ext&andOr4=and&textField5=&selectField5=tmlookup_ext&selectWithin=&selectStatus=&selectDateStatus=&fromDate=1865-01-01&toDate=2013-01-15&selectMaxDoc=500&selectDocsPerPage=10

Unless I have that jsessionid number, I cannot use simple_html_dom to spider the results with a custom form.

Is there a smart way of obtaining that session id? Once I have the session id, I can generate the search url and just play around the search results in a much meaningful manner.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the jsessionid as a cookie when entering the search page. Your spider must also obtain this cookie before sending search requests.

Here comes an example how this can be done. The example will use the [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/manual/tr/package.http.http-request2.php) package from the PEAR repositories.

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$url = 'http://www.cipo.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/tmSrch.do?lang=eng';
$request = new HTTP_Request2($url);
$response = $request->send();
$cookies = $response->getCookies();

foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
    if($cookie['name'] === 'JSESSIONID') {
        $jsessionid = $cookie['value'];
        break;
    }   
}

// play around with it
echo $jsessionid;
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it can be the magic key. I've looked at the pear page, but cannot figure out what package I need to install? I've not dealt with it before...

Comment: I found the download link. I am able to generate the session id. But when I substitute it in the link, I still get a session expired error.

Comment: Nevermind. It looks like if I run the simple_html_dom, instead of manually opening the link, everything works fine. 

THANK YOU so very much!